# Javascript stopping form from passing data

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, if-statement

resolved my javascript issue. Sorry it was mainly my fault as i copied and pasted my code instead of rewriting it out again. Strange thing is that it doesn't seem to pass the variables from the form to the process page as i have echo'd the SQL statement back out. This form did work previously to the java script all i added in was Post Code: for each row and even after deleting the javascript it still doesn't work :S
Sorry deadline tomorrow and im panicing.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function checkForm()
            {
                var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
                if(username.length < 5)
                {
                    alert("Username is to short");
                    return false;
                }
                else if (username.length<16)
                {
                    alert("Username is to long");
                    return false;
                }

                var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
                if(firstName.length <3)
                {
                    alert("Forname is to short");
                    return false;
                }

                var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
                if (lastName.length <3)
                {
                    alert("Surname is to short");
                    return false;
                }

                var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
                if (address.length <8)
                {
                    alert("Address is to short");
                    return false;
                }

                var town = document.getElementById('town').value;
                if (town.length <3)
                {
                    alert ("Town is to short");
                    return false;
                }

                var postCode = document.getElementById('postCode').value;
                if (postCode.length <6)
                {
                    alert ("Invalid Post Code");
                    return false;
                }
                else if (postCode.length>8)
                {
                    alert("Invalid Post Code");
                    return false;
                }


                var cardType = document.getElementById('cardType').value;
                if (cardType.length <3)
                {
                    alert ("Please enter a valid card type");
                    return false;
                }

                var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
                if (password.length <6)
                {
                    alert ("You password must be between 6-12 characters");
                    return false;
                }
                else if(password.length>12)
                {
                    alert ("Your password must be between 6-12 characters");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }


            }

            function checkUsername()
            {
                var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
                var element = document.getElementById('username1');
                if(username.length < 5)
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Username is to short";
                    element.style.color = "red";
                }
                else if (username.length >16)
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Username is to long";
                    element.style.color = "red";
                }
                else
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Username";
                    element.style.color = "green";
                }
            }
            function checkFname()
            {
                var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
                var element = document.getElementById('firstname1');
                if(firstName.length < 3)
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Forname is to short";
                    element.style.color = "red";
                }
                else
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Forname";
                    element.style.color = "green";
                }
            }
            function checkLname()
            {
                var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
                var element = document.getElementById('surname1');
                if(lastName.length < 3)
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Surname is to short";
                    element.style.color = "red";
                }
                else
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Surname";
                    element.style.color = "green";
                }
            }
            function checkAddress()
            {
                var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
                var element = document.getElementById('address1');
                if(address.length < 8)
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Address is to short";
                    element.style.color = "red";
                }
                else
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Address";
                    element.style.color = "green";
                }
            }
            function checkTown()
            {
                var town = document.getElementById('town').value;
                var element = document.getElementById('town1');
                if(town.length < 3)
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Town is to short";
                    element.style.color = "red";
                }
                else
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Town";
                    element.style.color = "green";
                }
            }
            function checkPostCode()
            {
                var postCode = document.getElementById('postCode').value;
                var element = document.getElementById('postcode1');
                if(postCode.length < 6)
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Post code is to short";
                    element.style.color = "red";
                }
                else if (postCode.length>8)
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Post Code To Long";
                    element.style.color = "red";
                }
                else
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Post Code";
                    element.style.color = "green";
                }
            }

                function checkCard()
                {
                    var cardType = document.getElementById('cardType').value;
                    var element = document.getElementById('card1');
                    if(cardType.length < 3)
                    {
                        element.innerHTML = "Card is to short";
                        element.style.color = "red";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    element.innerHTML = "Card Type";
                    element.style.color = "green";
                    }
                }
                function checkPassword()
            {
                var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
                var element = document.getElementById('password1');
                if(password.length < 6)
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Password is to short";
                    element.style.color = "red";
                }
                else if (password.length>16)
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Password is to long";
                    element.style.color = "red";
                }
                else
                {
                    element.innerHTML = "Password";
                    element.style.color = "green";
                }
            }

</script>


    <p><b><h3>Welcome User Please Register</h3></b></p>
    <form action="registerUserProcess.php" id="registerUserForm" method="post" name="registerUserForm" >

    <table> 
    <tr><td><label id="username1">Username:</label></td><td><input id="username" type="text" size="16" onBlur='checkUsername();'/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label id="firstname1">Forename:</label></td><td><input id="firstName" type="text" size="20" onBlur="checkFname();" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label id="surname1">Surname:</label></td><td><input id="lastName" type="text" size="30" onBlur="checkLname();" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label id="address1">Address:</label></td><td><input id="address" type="text" size="50" onBlur="checkAddress();" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input id="address2" type="text" size="50" onBlur="" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label id="town1">Town:</label></td><td><input id="town" type="text" size="50" onBlur="checkTown();" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label id="postcode1">Post Code:</label></td><td> <input type="text" id="postCode" size="8" onBlur="checkPostCode();" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label id="contact1">Contact No:</label></td><td> <input type="number" id="contact" size="12" onBlur="checkContactNo();" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Card Number:</td><td><input type="number" id="cardNo1" size="4" /> - <input type="number" id="cardNo2" size="4" /> - <input type="number" id="cardNo3" size="4" /> - <input type="number" id="cardNo4" size="4" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label id="card1">Card Type</label></td><td> <input type="text" id="cardType" size="8" onBlur="checkCard();" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email Address:</td><td><input id="emailAddress" type="text" size="50" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label id="password1">Password:</label></td><td><input id="password" type="password" size="16" onBlur="checkPassword();" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label id="terms1">Accept Terms & Conditions:</label></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="termsConditions" value="yes" onBlur="checkTerms();" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="reset" id="resetForm" value="Reset" id="resetForm" /></td><td><input type="submit" id="submitUser" value="Submit" id="submitUser" onSubmit='return checkForm();' /></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code.

Comment: The very first function (`checkForm`) of your code is weird. The lines after the first 'if-else' statement will never be executed, as the function will be finished with either `return false` or `return true`.

Comment: How do i go about resolving this solution ? i thought that it may be getting stuck after the first if statement as the other cells don't validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said, check your syntax. In `checkform()`, it should be

```
else if (username.length > 16)) instead of < 16
```

and in `checkUsername()` you spelled length wrong.

But your main problem is in your returns. In `checkform()` you should only put `return true` at the end when everything has been validated, or else the function just exit after the first validation.

You could also refactor all of this. You've got plenty of function that do almost the same thing. If you make one function that take minimum characters, maximum characters and the control to validate in parameters, you could do all of your code in 20 to 30 lines.

Plus, it seems like you copy-pasted some of your functions without changing the name of the variables or the targeted control. In fact, you assign `Username` as a variable in every function, but change the name in the condition, meaning you use an unassign variable.

Comment: Iv taken out all the return trues and just taken the else statment out. but it still wont validate the second cell down :S iv checked the speling on the second cell and dont understand why it can only validate the first cell it comes too

Comment: Well with your coding, if the first cell is invalid, it wont validate the rest. If you want it to validate everything even if some are invalid, you must also remove all the `returns false`. A trick would be to assign a variable at `true` by default and `false` if something doesn't validate and then, at the end, check this variable and return `true` if everything is still correct.

Comment: if (!isNAN(contact)) { element.style.color = "green"; is the only section that is refusing to work :S any ideas on what iv doen wrong thanks

Comment: If I get it right, this is for a phone number. `IsNaN` checks if the input is a number and a number only. Meaning you cant put `-` or `()` or even spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Function: checkForm():

You need to change the second else if to:

```
else if (username.length<16)) needs to be > 16.
```

--

Function: checkUsername():

You have incorrectly spelled length. Change it to:

```
else if (username.length>16)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is too much code for one question, but I noticed a few things in the first function:

```
else if (username.length<16) // This should probably be username.length > 16
{
    alert("Username is to long");
    return false;
}

if (isNAN(contact)) // this should probably be !isNaN(contact)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know if its my function checkForm thats stopping after the first set of IF statements? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled length in the following: `username.lenght>16`

This is the reason your too long isn't working.

```
        function checkUsername()
        {
            var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            var element = document.getElementById('username1');
            if(username.length < 5)
            {
                element.innerHTML = "Username is to short";
                element.style.color = "red";
            }
            else if (username.lenght>16)
            {
                element.innerHTML = "Username is to long";
                element.style.color = "red";
            }
            else
            {
                element.style.color = "green";
            }
        }
```